# how to use jquery this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Instead of using Click event i'm using .on for this.But i want to get the first td html when i click to the deleteArticle button.how would i select it using jquery this or something

```
$("#pard_admin").on("click", ".deleteArticle", function (event) {
    var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
});
```

in above this is relevant to the #pard_admin not for .deleteArticle i guess

```
$(".deleteArticle").click(function (event) {
    var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
});
```

In here this is relevant to `.deleteArticle`.So how would i use this select to get the just click `.deleteArticle` button closest `tr td first innetHHTMl` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your cases, `this` refers to the same element `.deleteArticle` if you click on `.deleteArticle`

Answer (score 0):

```
in above this is relevant to the #pard_admin not for .deleteArticle i guess
```

The above statement is incorrect.

[If you see docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

So `.deleteArticle` gets selected.

**And where  $(this)  is creating jQuery object from the  event.target.**

Answer (score 0):

You can define an event-listener-function that way without jquery:

```
var firstTd = document.getElementById('firstTd');

// or 

var firstTd = document.getElementsByClassName('firstTd')[0];

var eventHandler = function(td){
   console.log('firstTd: ',td);
}.bind(null,firstTd); // firstTd is the value for the first param

document.getElementsByClassName('deleteArticle')[0].addEventListener('click',eventHandler);
```

What the code does is to create a function by using bind. You can define values for the params of the created function:

```
var createdFunction = function(){}.bind(/* param for this */, /* first param for the created function */, /* second...*/)
```

When the createdFunction is called it has got access to a certain value you defined with bind (first param for the created function, second...).

When you want to get the whole table so that you can iterate over each td-element, you can do this the way:

```
 var firstTd = document.getElementById('firstTd');
 var eventHandler = function(td){

    console.log('table: ',this);
    console.log('table-children: ',this.children);
    var tableChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children); // casts htmlCollection to Array
    // now you can iterate over each td-element and use the Array-Methods (slice, split, reverse..)

 }.bind(document.getElementsByClassName('mytable')[0]); // sets html-table-element as

 document.getElementsByClassName('mytable')[0].addEventListener('click',eventHandler);
```

I hope this helps you.